# System cannot find Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.resources.dll when using Nuget package ServerAppFabric.Client

Tags: windows, appfabric

I've included  ServerAppFabric.Client.1.0.2912 in an application to do some basic cache diagnostics.  When I try to use the cache API though, I get this exception:

```
Caught unhandled exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigManager' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\src\Frank\Mischief\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Habanero.Commands.AppFabric.CacheDirCommand.<>c__DisplayClass9.<GetResolverForPath>b__8(Object o, ResolveEventArgs args) in C:\src\Habanero\Habanero\Commands\AppFabric\CacheDirCommand.cs:line 84
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

Any thoughts on how to help it find the resource DLL?  Its not in the nuget package...

The nuget package I'm using (http://nuget.org/packages/ServerAppFabric.Client/1.0.2912) comes with the following DLLs:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll
Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common.dll
Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Data.Common.dll
```

Comment: Where's that ServerAppFabric.Client assembly coming from? Is that a Habanero thing?

Comment: That is the nuget package, direct link: http://nuget.org/packages/ServerAppFabric.Client/1.0.2912.  I'll list the DLLs it comes with in the question

Comment: Not seen that Nuget package before, thanks. Have you installed AppFabric 1.1?

Comment: The service name is AppFabricCachingService, but I don't know how to check the version.  I use the powershell commands in DistributedCacheAdministration, none of the commands return a version and I don't see an entry in the installed programs and features list.

Comment: What's the path to the executable for the service? If it's 1.1, it should be C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\DistributedCacheService.exe. I'm wondering if it's a version conflict between the Nuget package and what you've got installed, it looks to me like the Nuget package is built for 1.0.

Comment: I see.  I don't have a c:\program files\appfabric directory, but I did install it within the last month (via WebMatrix).  WebMatrix is too automagical for me really, it camps on port 80 and doesn't leave much clues as to what it did.

Comment: Is there a direct installer for appfabric caching I could use instead?

Comment: Yes, you can install it through the Web Platform Installer, or download the installer from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27115. I didn't know you could install it through WebMatrix, wonder what that does...

Comment: my bad, when I said WebMatrix, I meant Web Platform Installer.  Thanks for the link to the direct download though, tahts what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with this NuGet. The package installs four dlls but only references the top-two of them :
[image]

MSBuild copy the two other references in the bin folder, maybe by detecting types from them are used in the two upper, but some other deployment tools can not.

Keep sure you have all the four references into your bin folder.